# TypeScript: error when using parseInt() on a number

Tags: typescript

The JavaScript function `parseInt` can be used to force conversion of a given parameter to an integer, whether that parameter is a string, float number, number, etc.

In JavaScript, `parseInt(1.2)` would yield `1` with no errors, however, in TypeScript, it throws an error during compilation saying:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

Am I missing something here or is it an expected behaviour from TypeScript?

Comment: yep that's the type checker for ya!

Comment: try `parseInt(""+1.2+"")`

Comment: `parseInt([2, 3])` returns `2` but that doesn't mean you should do it...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Don't use `parseInt` to do this operation -- use `Math.floor`.

Using `parseInt` to `floor` a number is not always going to yield correct results. `parseInt(4e21)` returns `4`, not `4e21`. `parseInt(-0)` returns `0`, not `-0`.

Comment: I don't think it's the correct way. This will produce a float number with no fractional part. But it is not an integer actually. For example you will expect a float number if you divide it by an integer.

Comment: The question asks for `string | number` `Math.floor()` only takes `number` so that doesn't work either.

One of the other answers suggests `Number()` which works but perhaps leaves you with a number with decimal places.

`Math.floor(Number(stringOrNumber))` seems like a sensible option, but also `parseInt("" + row.c, 10)` seems somewhat acceptable.

Comment: @Cosmo Your statement is incorrect since JavaScript does not have an integer type. JavaScript only has the type "number", which is an IEEE 754 double precision floating-point number.

Answer (score 18):

The function `parseInt` indeed expects a `string` in its first argument. Please check [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Usually you can omit the second, `radix` argument and then it will fall back to the default of `10`. But the safest is to always add the numeric system base as second argument (usually `10`).

If you'd like to *cast* a *general* value to `number`, you can use the `Number` function, like this.

```
var myNumber = Number(myGeneralValue);
```

Comment: " If this argument is not a string, then it is converted to one using the ToString abstract operation. " Documentation doesn't really describe a required type it should have. the input argument is simply just called "string" for historical reasons.

Answer (score 10):

I think other people have already given lots of valid answers here, but in my opinion the easiest approach would be to call `.toString()` on the original value, and to explicit the radix:

`parseInt((1.2).toString(), 10);`

Comment: template literals (template strings) `parseInt(`${X}`, 10)` is another option as well.

Comment: @Mahmoud I think the formatter cut the backticks around your template literal. I don't know how to render your syntax in a comment though...

Comment: `parseInt(\`${X}\`, 10)` you backslash them as such: this is a \\` backtick

Comment: @JohannesB how did you do it?

Comment: Like I said `If you add a \ backslash before a tick \\`, it keeps the tick inside code formatting`

Comment: @JohannesB Thank you, I hadn't seen your edit when I asked the question :)

Answer (score 5):

Look at the typing:

```
  parseInt(string: string, radix?: number): number;
                   ^^^^^^
```

The first argument needs to be a string. That's in line with the spec:

> `parseInt (string , radix)`
>       The **`parseInt`** function produces an integer value dictated by interpretation of the contents of the *string* argument according to the specified *radix*.

In normal JS, the first argument is coerced to a string, based on the following rule in the spec:

> 1. Let *inputString* be ToString(*string*).

which is why `parseInt(1.2)` works.

Note that the spec allows *radix* to be `undefined`, which is the same as omitting it, hence the question mark in the `radix?: number` part of the signature. In this case, of course, it defaults to 10 (unless the string looks like `0xabc`).

As mentioned in other answers, `parseInt` is not the best solution anyway if what you really want to do is a floor or truncation operation.

Answer (score 5):

A bit old but to put another way in to the pot:

`Math.trunc();`

see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) for details.

Comment: This should be the correct answer as its output is the closest to `parseInt`

Answer (score 4):

Why would you use parseInt in this case? Just use `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil`. `parseInt` expects a string as an argument and not a number. Hence your error

Answer (score 1):

There are different manifestations when negative numbers between 'Math.floor' and 'parseInt'.

you should use this:
1.2 | 0

or (1.2).toFixed(0)

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.floor(Number(val)) // Accepts String or Number, rounded down integer 
//OR
Math.round(Number(val)) // Accepts String or Number, give nearest Integer
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?