# Build:Argument of type 'string | 1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this typescript code:

```
categoryColumnWide: number = 0;

this.categoryColumnWide = parseInt(storage.getItem('categoryColumnWide') || 1);
```

Giving me the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Build:Argument of type 'string | 1' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'string'.

Can someone help me with this? I just upgraded to a new version of Typescript and this message is appearing now in multiple places. When I hover over categoryColumnWide it says it's a "number"

FYI As far as I know I am using Typescript 2.1

Comment: if `storage.getItem('categoryColumnWide')` return a falsy value then `1` will be chosen and passed as parametter to `parseInt` and since `parseInt` expects a `string`, it says that you can not assign a number to a string!

Comment: Changing it to `parseInt(storage.getItem(...) || "1")` or `Number((storage.getItem(...) || 1))` will solve the problem!

Comment: Or you can check if the item is in the storage before start using it like: `if(storage.getItem('categoryColumnWide')) { storage.setItem('categoryColumnWide', '1'); }`!

Comment: or just `parseInt(storage.getItem('categoryColumnWide')) || 1`

Comment: @AlekseyL. what if `storage.getItem('categoryColumnWide')` returned `"0"`?

Comment: Possible solutions: [**Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475166/typescript-error-when-using-parseint-on-a-number) and [**Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667713/typescript-converting-a-string-to-a-number)!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir you are right - it can cause not desired behavior

Comment: ... and [**Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437476/in-typescript-how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric)!

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt` requires string argument

your code passes `storage.getItem('categoryColumnWide')` (string) or `1` (number)

try passing `1` as string

```
this.categoryColumnWide = parseInt(storage.getItem('categoryColumnWide') || '1');
```