# Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' using ParseInt

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that calculates a lighter/darker color by hex.

On my localhost it runs just fine.. but when I try to build in Angular I get the error:

```
ERROR in src/app/requests.service.ts:1611:17 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
1611  R = parseInt(R * (100 + percent) / 100);

src/app/requests.service.ts:1612:17 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
1612  G = parseInt(G * (100 + percent) / 100);

src/app/requests.service.ts:1613:17 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
1613  B = parseInt(B * (100 + percent) / 100);
```

Here is my code:

```
  adjust(color, percent) {
  
   var R = parseInt(color.substring(1,3),16);
   var G = parseInt(color.substring(3,5),16);
   var B = parseInt(color.substring(5,7),16);

   R = parseInt(R * (100 + percent) / 100);
   G = parseInt(G * (100 + percent) / 100);
   B = parseInt(B * (100 + percent) / 100);

   R = (R<255)?R:255;
   G = (G<255)?G:255;
   B = (B<255)?B:255;

   var RR = ((R.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+R.toString(16):R.toString(16));
   var GG = ((G.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+G.toString(16):G.toString(16));
   var BB = ((B.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+B.toString(16):B.toString(16));

   return "#"+RR+GG+BB;
}
```

I'm calling the function using:

```
 adjust("#345678", -70)
```

I also tried defining the function parameters like this:

```
adjust(color:string, percent:number) {
```

but it wasn't successful.

Any ideas would be great. Thank you!

Comment: You're calling `parseInt` on a *number*. I'm guessing you want `Math.floor`?

Comment: you supplied parseInt() with a number instead of string

Comment: @JaredSmith the function works exactly as I would hope.. The outcome of the function is correct, but when I try to build this is the issue.. I tried `Math.floor` on each of the `parseInt` and the function didn't return the correct information

Comment: @maziyank can you elaborate? I don't understand what the issue is

Comment: this problem is may be similiar to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475166/typescript-error-when-using-parseint-on-a-number

Comment: @maziyank, I tried replacing the `parseInt` with `Math.floor` but the function no longer works.. it outputs the incorrect information, whereas `parseInt` has the correct information

Comment: try R = parseInt("" + R * (100 + percent) / 100); and so on

Comment: @Simon you may want `Math.round` instead of `Math.floor`, hard to say since you don't specify what "doesn't work" actually means. But mazlyank is correct, `parseInt` takes a *string*, not a number. Javascript is loose enough to accept it (which is why it works in your browser) but the Typescript compiler (correctly) complains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up figuring out where the issue was.. here is the code that worked:

```
adjust(color, percent) {

   var R = parseInt(color.substring(1,3),16);
   var G = parseInt(color.substring(3,5),16);
   var B = parseInt(color.substring(5,7),16);

   R = Math.floor(R * (100 + percent) / 100);
   G = Math.floor(G * (100 + percent) / 100);
   B = Math.floor(B * (100 + percent) / 100);

   R = (R<255)?R:255;
   G = (G<255)?G:255;
   B = (B<255)?B:255;

   var RR = ((R.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+R.toString(16):R.toString(16));
   var GG = ((G.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+G.toString(16):G.toString(16));
   var BB = ((B.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+B.toString(16):B.toString(16));

   return "#"+RR+GG+BB;
}
```

I had to change the second row of `parseInt`s to `Math.floor`.

Answer (score 1):

I check your code. The method of parseInt in typescript use is like this.

```js
parseInt(string)
```

So I change your function like this. You can see below.

```js
function adjust(color:string, percent:number) {
  
  var R = parseInt(color.substring(1,3),16);
  var G = parseInt(color.substring(3,5),16);
  var B = parseInt(color.substring(5,7),16);

  R = parseInt(R * (100 + percent) / 100 + '');
  G = parseInt(G * (100 + percent) / 100 + '');
  B = parseInt(B * (100 + percent) / 100 + '');

  R = (R<255)?R:255;
  G = (G<255)?G:255;
  B = (B<255)?B:255;

  var RR = ((R.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+R.toString(16):R.toString(16));
  var GG = ((G.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+G.toString(16):G.toString(16));
  var BB = ((B.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+B.toString(16):B.toString(16));

  return "#"+RR+GG+BB;
}
```

Comment: There's no need for a hack like this, JS/TS has functions for converting floats to integers.